# How to install Owncloud on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, php

I wanted to install Owncloud on my VPS running CentOS 6.5. I followed the instructions on the [official owncloud website](http://software.opensuse.org/download/package?project=isv:ownCloud:community&package=owncloud) but when I run the command `yum install owncloud` it says

```
    Error: Package: owncloud-server-8.0.0-27.1.noarch (isv_ownCloud_community)
       Requires: php >= 5.4.0
       Installed: php-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (@updates)
           php = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Available: php-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php = 5.3.3-38.el6
```

So I followed [these instructions](http://adminforge.de/webserver/php/php-5-4-oder-5-5-upgrade-unter-debian-centos/) (actually there are a lot of sites that provide more or less the same instructions) and installed PHP 5.5 over the Remi repository. After running `yum install owncloud` again it says

```
    Error: Package: php-gd-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Installed: php-common-5.5.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.22-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
    Error: Package: php-mbstring-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Installed: php-common-5.5.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.22-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
    Error: Package: php-pdo-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Installed: php-common-5.5.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.22-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
    Error: Package: php-ldap-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
       Installed: php-common-5.5.22-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi-php55)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.5.22-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
```

It required PHP 5.4 or greater but then it requires PHP 5.3 ???

Comment: You have to add old repo for php 5.3 and install it, Then remove old repo from your repositories.

Comment: Are you sure you added the owncloud repo for CentOS 6 and not the one for CentOS 7?

Comment: @jordanm I removed the owncloud repo and readded the one for CentOS 6 to be sure. Still the same problem.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh You say I have to wipe all php, then install 5.3, then remove the repo for 5.3? But owncloud requires 5.4 or greater!?

Comment: Yes, you don't need them not only, but also you make conflict.

Comment: But isn't PHP 5.3 part of the standard CentOS repository? Do I have to remove that one? I can install PHP 5.3 without adding any repository. So which one do I have to remove?

Comment: You should install php 5.6 higher from webtatic repos when you want to install owncloud 8.0.xx from owncloud repos.Why dont you download owncloud 9.1.3 tarball from owncloud site? You can upload big size of files to owncloud 9.1.3.That owncloud 8.x can not do it. I have been done it on SL 7.2 64 bit with php 7.1 from webtatic repos.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to install Owncloud on CentOS 6.5. The problem was that Owncloud required some additional PHP packages. When trying to install them from the standard repository of CentOS I couldn't get any newer version of PHP but 5.3. I added [Remi Collet's repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en) and installed Owncloud by running `yum --enablerepo=remi install owncloud` which automatically installed PHP packages of version 5.4 (before I removed all PHP packages and installed version 5.4 by running `yum --enablerepo=remi install php`).